# WooCommerce - send a custom event to Google Tag Manager when order is placed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to emit / send a custom event to Google Tag Manager when an order is eventually placed, so this order can be tracked.

The custom event should NOT be sent each time, when the WoocCommerce Thank you page is loaded, because the order would be tracked multiple times, when the page is reloaded.

So it should only be sent once for every order, when the final submit button is clicked AND the checkout form is valid.

I looked for wooCommerce DOM events, but couldn't found a suitable one...

I know there are plugins for that, but a plugin would be overkill for that I guess. We are a web agency and try to use as few plugins as possible and only necessary ones.

Unfortunately I have no clue, how I would emit an event on order placed... Any ideas or hints or even the solution to this? ;)

Thanks in advance, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem. As you mentioned, a plugin would be likely most suitable in the universe of Wordpress.

The next best solution is to open the documentation of woocommerce and see if you can find a callback for a successful order there. You emit an event from that callback if woocommerce doesn't do it already, which I believe you've checked.

Another solution would be sending the conversion on thank you loads, but have a logic in place that would not send more than one event with the same order id. And only when order id is defined. That would require you to surface the order id or find where it's surfaced.

A simpler yet dirty solution fitting woocommerce would be to just fire the conversion on the thank you page, but generate a cookie that would block the tag from firing again and let the cookie expire in N minutes, depending on whether you want to track repeated conversions from the same client.